# Infinite Limit of a Function and its Derivative

Tags: calculus

Suppose f is a differentiable function for which the infinite lim f(x) and infinite lim df(x)/dx both exist and are finite. Which of the following must be true?
(A) the infinite limit df(x)/dx is zero
(B) the infinite limit of the second derivative of f(x) is zero
(C) the infinite limit f(x) is equal to the infinite limit df(x)/dx
(D) f is a constant function
(E) df(x)/dx is a constant function

Source: GRE Mathematics Subject Test 9768, Number 34, Page 32

Comment: Okay, but like if the infinite limit of df/dx isn't zero, then the infinite limit doesn't exist???? im stuck between A and B

Comment: Does the function need to be twice differentiable?

Comment: @AritroPathak  didn't say that therefore it must be A LOLOL

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try examining $f(x)=\arctan(x)$

Comment: @ qbert  I think the choice of f(x) = arctanx is a good one. So, we may say option (A) is correct. However, the infinite limit of the second derivative of arctanx is zero. This makes option (B) correct too. Is there anything I am getting wrong?

Comment: Yes it was only intended to eliminate most of the options. I would eliminate b since you are not even guaranteed the second derivative exists!

Comment: okay I can see your point